# Rendering Inside ObserveEvent (Dynamic Plot Generation)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'm trying to recreate https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/ but by adding plots through a button. I think this needs me to modify the `server.r` code on the link along these lines (the chartname related variable are created through `reactiveValues`) -

```
observeEvent(
      input$buttonAddData, 
      {
         ...
         newchartname = c(newchartname,newchartname)
         output[[newchartname]] = renderPlot({
            ...
         })
      }
)

output$plots = renderUI(
      {

         plot_output_list <- lapply(
            seq(length(allthechartnames)), 
            function(i) {
               plotname <- paste(
                  isolate(allthechartnames)[i]
               )
               plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
               cat(plotname,'\n')
            }
         )

         # Convert the list to a tagList - this is necessary for the list of items
         # to display properly.
         do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)

      }
   )
```

But this seems to not enter the original loop of creating the chart itself inside the observeEvent which results in no charts inside the renderUI block.

Any tips?

Comment: You should not call a render function inside an observer.  Instead, use `reactiveValues` and change the value of a reactive value in an observer, and use that value as a dependency in the render function

Comment: @daattali - In the above code, I tried adding an element to the list of `reactivevalues` (called <chartname>) and assigning the chart created inside the `observe` to it. I'm not sure how to substitute this in the render bit. I can't do `plotname = <listofreactivevalues>$<chartname>`.

Comment: It might be easier to help understand the problem/solution if you can provide working code rather than snippets

Comment: I'm trying to do something along these lines = https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/ but instead of a defined slider, I want to have a button that generates random data and adds a plot for each random data generation. Does that help? If not, please let me know, I will write up my version of the code and post it on the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't really understand the code in your question so I kind of ignored it and just took Winston's code from the gist and made it work with a button instead of a slider.  I hope this is what you meant?  Also, I did have to use render inside an observer which I'm not happy about :/

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    headerPanel("Dynamic number of plots"),

    mainPanel(
      actionButton("addplot", "Add plot"),
      uiOutput("plots")
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {

    # A variable that keeps track of the number of plots we have
    values <- reactiveValues(
      numPlots = 1
    )

    # Whenever the "add plot" button is pressed, increment num plots by 1
    observeEvent(input$addplot, {
      values$numPlots <- values$numPlots + 1
    })

    # Dynamically generate the UI that creates all the plots
    output$plots <- renderUI({
      # Create a list of `plotOutput` objects (for each plot, use a unique ID)
      plot_output_list <- lapply(1:values$numPlots, function(i) {
        plotname <- paste("plot", i, sep="")
        plotOutput(plotname, height = 280, width = 250)
      })

      # Place all the plot outputs inside a shiny `tagList()`
      do.call(tagList, plot_output_list)
    })

    # Every time the number of plots changes (button is clicked),
    # re-generate the render functions for all the plots
    observeEvent(values$numPlots, {
      for (i in 1:values$numPlots) {
        local({
          my_i <- i
          plotname <- paste("plot", my_i, sep="")

          output[[plotname]] <- renderPlot({
            plot(1:my_i, 1:my_i,
                 xlim = c(1, values$numPlots),
                 ylim = c(1, values$numPlots),
                 main = paste("1:", my_i, ".  n is ", values$numPlots, sep = "")
            )
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
))
```

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried to run it but it said max_plots not found. My need for a button is exactly to overcome the need for max_plots altogether. I might have 10 plots, I might have 100, I don't know.

Comment: oops, my bad, forgot to run it on a clean session. Should work now.

Comment: Am I right to think that since the max_plots is placed inside the observe, I can call a reactive value to it too?

Comment: Great! Thanks, this works! Just for my knowledge, why is using local a bad practice?

Comment: My code doesn't have `max_plots`, instead it uses a reactive value. I'm not quite sure I understand that question

Comment: Using local isn't bad (from what I know at least) -- using a render inside an observer is not advisable to my knowledge. I believe I saw Joe Cheng and Winston Chang (two of the authors of Shiny) mention that a few times, though I might be wrong.  Although maybe I'm wrong, perhaps they said that using render inside a `reactive` is bad (and that I can see why it's bad, because reactive values can cache and you don't want to have side effects inside them)

Comment: I asked the max_plots question but then I tried it out. I don't need to have one observe to increment the values and another to add the charts in a loop, I do my random data generation inside the first observe itself and also add a chart there itself. And I understand the possibility of side effects inside the reactive. Thanks for taking the time!